# Session or SessionFactory which one to Use in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, quote, checkoutsession

I am have been working on a payment method where I need Current Quote

So I used

```
\Magento\Checkout\Model\SessionFactory $checkoutSession
```

and then get Quote from the Checkout session using

```
$this->_checkoutSession->create()->getQuote()
```

one of my fellow developer who was reviewing my code has told me to use `Session` instead of `SessionFactory`

I know some differences but I am not sure why he changed it and what you guys prefer to use

I have checked [This Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/227456/78648) but haven't got a satisfactory answer

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a factory for the class `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` because factories are used when we want to get a completely new object without any data inside it and then fill it with data based on something (usually an ID).

In this case, each customer will have at most one active quote stored in the session and you are retrieving this active quote from the session.

You are not loading any object directly for avoiding any shared object instance.